# How to create SQL Server Agent Queued jobs?

Tags: sql-server, perfmon

There is a perfmon counter "Queued jobs" in perfmon object "SQLAgent:Jobs".

How to create a job queue that will reflect in this perfmon counter?

Can I get this queued job info from somewhere else like DMV?

Comment: My guess is that this reflect when you have so many jobsteps of a certain kind to be started simultaneously so you reach the max for that jobstep. Should be pretty easy to test and see if a bunch will trigger a positive value for this counter. I.e., nothing that you can schedule explicitly.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635757/sql-agent-job-to-execute-as-queue

Comment: I tried a job with 20 steps, no luck. @Tibor,

Comment: Try more. You can use sp_enum_sqlagent_subsystems to see the limit for each job subsystem. On my SQL server, I have 80 for T-SQL and 4 for CmdExec, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL Server Agent has a maximum worker thread setting that limits the total number of threads that can run jobs at any given time. When you hit this limit, you will get a warning message that the thread limit has been hit and the job queued for execution. When this occurs, that counter increments to record the fact that there is a queued job.

This is also true for job steps, which have their own worker thread limit for each subsystem and a performance counter under SQLAgent:JobSteps to record the queued steps.

This queueing mechanism is not something you can manually initiate or control, it is an in-built queueing mechanism to manage the worker threads used by SQL Agent.

[See here](https://mssqlwiki.com/sqlwiki/sql-server-agent/sql-agent-maxworkerthreads-and-agent-subsystem/) for more info. The max worker thread count is # of CPUS*100. Run [sp_enum_sqlagent_subsystems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-enum-sqlagent-subsystems-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to see the max worker threads for individual subsystems.

You can test this out yourself, though it is easier to test the subsystem queue behaviour than the SQL Agent job queue behaviour.

Create a number (6 or more, depends on the limit for the PowerShell subsystem) of one-step SQL Agent jobs to run a PowerShell command (`Start-Sleep -Seconds 60`) and execute them simultaneously. Job Activity Monitor will show something similar to below

[image]

And if you're monitoring the performance counter SQLAgent:JobSteps - Queued Steps, you will see it increase:

[image]